# Finish app when phone goes to sleep and save history

Tags: android, history, activity-finish

I have a chat app, what I want to do is to end app when phone goes to sleep or when it goes to background. I did this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    finish();
    super.onPause();
}
```

What happens after this is that back button (or action bar back) doesn't goes at the previous activity but at main activity instead. History of app isn't saved anymore. I need to save history but at the same time finish app on sleep or when it is in background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the broadcast receiver for that, then you can do all the changes which you can do once your onReceive() called.

In your manifest add the receiver and intent filter like this

```
 <receiver android:name=".ScreenOnOffReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And you can put all your logic in your java code.

```
 public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
     {
                  // some code
     }
             if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
     {
                  // put your all logic here
     }
 }
```

}

Hope this will help.